# Bench PSU "Ground-Earth-Reference" connector - what's it called?

Tags: power-supply, identification, grounding, safety, hardware

I have need of some of those little metal links that let you bridge between GND and Earth posts on a typical benchtop-PSU.  But I'm damned if I can contrive a google search that yields any useful results.

If you don't know what I mean, Dave Jones of the EEVBlog did an excellent video about a related topic, and he shows one clearly at this point (pause it as soon as it loads).

https://youtu.be/xaELqAo4kkQ?t=883

... I'm referring to the piece of metal that is clamped between the green and black terminals of that PSU.

What are those things called?

Comment: For some reason I'm reluctant to use a paperclip for this purpose. :)

Comment: You could buy some thin brass sheet (like I did, 0.5 mm will be fine, no need for 0.9 mm) and fashion some yourself (it's on the project list...).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, not a bad idea at all.  Scroll-saw the basic outline, drill out the important bits and file away the rest!  Could probably do a couple at once to save time.

Answer (score 1):

The only ones I've been able to find are [here](https://www.electronicsurplus.com/h-h-smith-1828-connector-banana-jacks-shorting-links-only-package-of-10), but looking for 'Shorting Links' and the like doesn't seem to lead to much else.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Figure 1. A search for **4mm banana post link** finds this sort of thing. Image source: eBay.*

Comment: Yeah, I tried probably 20 variations on this wording in my searches.  No dice.  Quite a few pictures of bananas though.  Bananas are not an effective PSU earthing method, at least not for long.

Comment: eBay listing: "Ended 15 July, 2021."

Answer (score 0):

These seem way too expensive for what they are, but it is the product you asked for: https://www.newark.com/pomona/4115/shorting-bar-for-binding-posts/dp/20H0132

Comment: It's Pomona, they usually charge about twenty times what things are worth.